# Get first item of list value of each object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list where I can get alot of objects.

```
List<string[]> registros
```

[image]

That I want to do is to get register 0 of each object, for example object 0

[image]

I want to get only "CORP" value and so on with all objects. So I try

```
foreach (var reg in registros[0])
{
    var list = new[]
    {
        new { registros, Name = "Unidad" }
    }.ToList();
    var a = list;
}
```

But it only return one object with all register inside it. What am I doing wrong? How can I create list of first item of all objects?

Comment: you don't need to loop through registros[0], you will get your oth object in registros[0]..

Comment: Are you wanting to return a collection containing all the values of the first item?

Comment: Maybe `registros.Select(r=>r?.FirstOrDefault()).Where(r=>r!=null).ToList()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries):

```
var s =
    registros
        .Select( r => r?.FirstOrDefault() )
        .Where( r => r != null )
        .ToList();
```

- Line 3 iterates over all `List` items and selects the first (if available) or `null` otherwise.
- Line 4 removes those that are `null`.
- Line 5 converts to a `List`.

[Here is a .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V44NBH) of the above code.

---

Responding to [your comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48657198/get-first-item-of-list-value-of-each-object#comment84312256_48657298), here is how to rename items in the list, without selecting:

```
foreach ( var list in registros )
{
    if ( list != null && list.Length > 0 )
    {
        list[0] = "Unidad";
    }
}
```

And [a .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BL1X2L) for it.

Comment: And what about if I want to rename object, instead receive [0],[1],[2]..etc. rename it with default value like Unity? is that possible?

Comment: @Pepe I don't know what "rename object" means. Since your `List` constains `string[]` entries, you could change the _value_ of items in the `string[]`. I've updated my answer, in case it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to do it in this way using LINQ:

```
List<string[]> registros = GetRegistros();
var onlyFirstInEach = registros.SelectMany(x => x.Take(1)).ToList();
```